# how to generate html table based on number of rows entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to create a table using jquery. The number of rows the table will be determined from input box. The number of columns are known. After submitting that, a table gets generated. Tried creating a fiddle.
Am very new to jquery . Not sure how to proceed.

[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/3/)

```
        <form>
        Number of rows to be generated
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="table-row-num" value="3">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="table-gen">
        <p>Table generated here after clicking submit</p>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="name" placeholder="text goes here...">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to show your attempt to solve the question so one can help solve it.

Comment: Things like that are pretty easy using Mustache https://mustache.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your fiddle updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/17/

This is the jquery code:

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var table = $("#resultTable");
    var rowNum = parseInt($("#table-row-num").val(), 10);
    var resultHtml = '';

    for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        resultHtml += ["<tr>", 
     "<td>", 
      (i+1),
     "</td>",
     '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
     '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
     '</tr>'].join("\n");
    }  

    table.html(resultHtml);
    return false; 
});
```

I wish you luck with implementation. :)

Edit: 
If you want to allow number of rows to be on range between minimum and maximum number the best solution is to use native html 5 validation. 
This is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/20/

Comment: thanks georgi. If i want to restrict the number of rows? say max 10 rows ?

Comment: i tried this but some error occurs after the submission
http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/18/

Comment: I have edited the answer. There is link to second jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great now!

Answer (score 2):

Say you gave an id to your `<table>` element

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" id="tableElement">
```

and an `onclick` attribute to your button

```
<button onclick="addRows()">Submit</button>
```

your (pure) Javascript should look like this :

```
function addRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableElement');
    var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById('table-row-num').value);
    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
        var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
        var cell3 = document.createElement('td');
        var input1 = document.createElement('input');
        var input2 = document.createElement('input');
        input1.type = "text";
        input2.type = "text";
        input1.placeholder = "Text goes here...";
        input2.placeholder = "Text goes here...";
        cell1.innerHTML = i.toString();
        cell2.appendChild(input1);
        cell3.appendChild(input2);
        tr.appendChild(cell1);
        tr.appendChild(cell2);
        tr.appendChild(cell3);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure the jquery code would be a lot smaller but trust me, your browser would respond a lot faster to pure Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

you can use `append` of jQuery.

```
var count = 30;
var row = "<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>";
for(var i=0; i< count; i++){
    $('#tableId tbody').append(row);
}

<table id="tableId"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle for you. Have a look

https://jsbin.com/hoyetu/edit?html,js,output

```
$('button').on('click', generate);

function generate(e) {
  var rows = $('#table-row-num').val();
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    html += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>' +
      '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>' +
      '</tr>';
  }
  $('table').html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fpd8dwtw/13/

```
$("#createTable").on("click", function (event){
event.preventDefault();
var noOfRows = $("#table-row-num").val();
var noOfCols = 3;  // fixed columns as you mentioned in the question
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var oTable = document.createElement("table");
for(var i =0; i < noOfRows; i++){
    var oTr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var j=0; j < noOfCols; j++){
        var oTd = document.createElement("td");
        oTd.innerHTML = "put your content here";
        oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    }
    oTable.appendChild(oTr);
}

$("#table-gen").html(oTable);
```

});