# How to Generate HTML table based on number of rows given in input type number

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a html table that is getting generated based on the response getting from backend api. I want to see only those many number of rows that user will select from input type number.
I have tried referring to other answers from stack overflow, but none of them is solving my problem because of having dynamic data.

This is the html part:

```
<label for="report" class="hideshow" style="color:black ; float:left ; font-weight: bold">Static Code Analysis Report</label>
                    <br/><center>
                        <label id="issues" style="font-size: 14px">Show</label>
                        <input type="number" id="table-row-num"  min="1" max="1000" style="font-size: 14px">
                        <label id="issues" style="font-size: 14px">No. of Issues</label>
                        <button id="submitButton">Go</button>
                    </center>
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="codeScanReportDiv">
                                <div class="codeReport" id="codeReport">
                                    <div class="reportTable">
                                        <table class="table table-striped" id="reportTable">
                                            <thead id="reportTableHead">
                                                <tr id="reportTableTR">
                                                    <th>Issue/Bug Description</th>
                                                    <th>Artifact Type</th>
                                                    <th>Count</th>
                                                    <th>Recommendation</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="reportTableBody">
                                                <tr id="reportTableData">

                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and following is the code present in js file :

```
sonarQubeIssueApi = localStorage.sonarQubeIssueApi + "?appName="+"otfa" + "&projectName="+"R5-9";
            getApi(sonarQubeIssueApi).done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                    $('#reportTable').find('tbody').append('<tr id=reportTableData><td>'+value.IssueDescription+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.drmArtifactType+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.count+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.recommendation+'</td></tr>');
                });
                loadingStop();
            }).fail(function () {
                loadingStop();
                bootbox.alert({
                    size: "medium",
                    title: "Sonar Qube is Down",
                    message: "Cannot get the issue list from SonarQube"
                });
            });
```

Please help me to generate only those many rows which user will select from table-row-num id. Any help is very much appreciated !!

I have tried to follow ([how to generate html table based on number of rows entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846984/how-to-generate-html-table-based-on-number-of-rows-entered),but) this is also not working for me...it is able to generate rows as entered by user..but only one entry from response(api response) is getting repeated in every row. Moreover, table heading is also not coming. Here is the code i have tried:

```
getApi(sonarQubeIssueApi).done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                    // $('#reportTable').find('tbody').append('<tr id=reportTableData><td>'+value.IssueDescription+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.drmArtifactType+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.count+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.recommendation+'</td></tr>');

                    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
                        var table = $("#reportTable");
                        var rowNum = parseInt($("#table-row-num").val(), 10);
                        var resultHtml = '';

                        for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
                            resultHtml += ["<tr id=reportTableData>", 
                         "<td>", 
                          (i+1),
                         "</td>",
                         '<td>'+value.IssueDescription+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.drmArtifactType+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.count+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.recommendation+'</td>',
                         '</tr>'].join("\n");
                        }  

                        table.html(resultHtml);
                        return false; 
                    });
```

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this what you tyring to do.

```
 getApi(sonarQubeIssueApi).done(function (data) {
     var table = $('#reportTableBody');
     var rowNum = parseInt($("#table-row-num").val(), 10);
     var table.html("");
     var filterData = data.slice(0, rowNum);
     $.each(filterData, function(key,value) {
          table.append('<tr id=reportTableData><td>'+value.IssueDescription+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.drmArtifactType+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.count+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.recommendation+'</td></tr>');
     });
 });
```

Comment: use 
var table = $('#reportTableBody');

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It is working...Can u please tell what I should do if by default i want to display 5 records, and on selection from input type, user selected records

Comment: parseInt($("#table-row-num").val() || 5, 10);